# Prove $\left.\frac{d}{dt}g(a(t),b(t))\right|_{t=0}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(a(0),b(0))a'(0)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(a(0),b(0))b'(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, chain-rule

> Let $g=g(x,y)$ be a differentiable real-valued function and let $a,b\colon\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be differentiable. Prove that $$\left.\frac{d}{dt}g(a(t),b(t))\right|_{t=0}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(a(0),b(0))a'(0)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(a(0),b(0))b'(0).$$

I tried as follow :

$$\frac{g(a(t),b(t))-g(a(0),b(0))}{t}=\frac{g(a(t),b(t))-g(a(0),b(t))+g(a(0),b(t))-g(a(0),b(0))}{t}$$

I know that $$\frac{g(a(0),b(t))-g(a(0),b(0))}{t}$$
$$=\frac{g(a(0),b(t))-g(a(0),b(0))}{b(t)-b(0)}\cdot \frac{b(t)-b(0)}{t}\to \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(a(0),b(0))b'(0)$$
when $t\to 0$, but how can I prove that 
$$\frac{g(a(t),b(t))-g(a(0),b(t))}{t}$$
$$=\frac{g(a(t),b(t))-g(a(0),b(0))}{a(t)-a(0)}\cdot \frac{a(t)-a(0)}{t}\to \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(a(0),b(0))a'(0)  \ \ ?$$

My problem is to prove that $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{g(a(t),b(t))-g(a(0),b(t))}{a(t)-a(0)}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(a(0),b(0)),$$
because the seconde variable in $g(a(t),b(t))$ moves when $t\to 0$. Any idea ?

Comment: I guess you need continuity of partial derivatives here, otherwise $\partial g/\partial x(a(0),b(0)), \partial g/\partial y(a(0),b(0))$ need not be defined.

Comment: @Gibbs: Let say that $g$ is $\mathcal C^1$.

Comment: I edited the text because it is indeed necessary that $g,a$, and $b$ are differentiable, otherwise the question does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can conclude that way. Since $g$ is differentiable at $(a(0),b(0))$, then, $$g(x,y)=g(a(0),b(0))+\nabla g(a(0),b(0))\cdot ((x,y)-(a(0),b(0))+o((x,y)-(a(0),b(0))).$$
Therefore, $$\frac{g(a(t),b(t))-g(a(0),b(0))}{t}=\nabla g(a(0),b(0))\cdot \left(\frac{a(t)-a(0)}{t},\frac{b(t)-b(0)}{t}\right)+o(1).$$
Taking $t\to 0$, the claim follow.